# How to efficiently change the data type of each key in a list of SortedSets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, sortedset

I'm using Python to process a Pandas DataFrame in which one of the columns is composed of `SortedSet`'s. This is part of the data for that column in the DataFrame:

```
>>> df['categories']

SortedSet([category(key=1, value=55), category(key=2, value=20, ...)])
SortedSet([category(key=3, value=100), category(key=4, value=80, ...)])
#...
```

I want to change the data type of the key in each entry from `int` to `list`, so it would go from the content above to this:

```
SortedSet([category(key=[1], value55), category(key=[2], value=20, ...)])
SortedSet([category(key=[3], value=100), category(key=[4], value=80, ...)])
```

I would probably be able to do so by iterating the list and changing each entry one by one, but I'm hoping there is a more efficient way to do so.

Does anyone have an idea on how can I do that, if possible?

Comment: Can you post your code snippet of what you've tried?

Comment: My best guess would be something like this:

`for category_set in df['categories']:
    for category in category_set:
        category.id = [category.id] # this doesn't work as is, I would need to check how to change from int to list`

But this has O(n²) complexity and for huge dataframes that would take too much time. This is why I don't want to use this approach.